# Expresso Store Fatal Error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException'

Tags: expresso-store

EE 2.9.0, store 2.5.0 - and anytime store code appears on a page this error occurs, exception of the cart, so it looks like it is tied to the products. Take the store product code out and it renders fine. Any other page with standard EE code and it renders fine. Anyone have any ideas?

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getEager()' in /home/d562657/public_html/admin/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:1993 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call('getEager', Array) #1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->getEager() #2 /home/d562657/public_html/admin/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(919): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('getEager', Array) #4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getEager() #5 /home/d562657/public_html/admin/expressionengine/third_party/_store/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php(281): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6 /home/d562657/public_html/admin/expressionengine/thi in /home/d562657/public_html/admin/expressionengine/third_party/store/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php on line 1993

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information if you expect anyone to be able to help you. What version of EE and Store are you using? What pages do you see this error? What steps do you need to recreate this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured it out, so we are posting it for the benefit of the community in case someone runs into this in the future. In order to upgrade store to the newest version, we renamed the store folder to '_store' in the third_party folder. For some reason this was being picked up by the store install in EE in only the front-end. The admin panel worked fine, but any store code with pricing in it threw the fatal error. This morning we moved that folder out of third_party and also tested it to being renamed '.store' and it works. So is the class being picked up on one side due to the underscore, but the admin ignores it.